# Dockerfile, how to reduce the size of changed layer?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have a project there are some big files and folders. some files are mostly static(*.params). Now I hope to publish static files/folders as an independent layer. Below is my project structure.

```sh
/app
  /static_files
     /a.params
     /b.params
     /dynamic1.py
     /dynamic2.py
  /static_folders
     /dynamic1.py
     /dynamic2.py
     /dynamic3.py
     /folder1
  /dynamic1
     /dynamic.py
  /dynamic2
     /dynamic.py
  run.py
  requirements.txt
```

and the Dockerfile is

```yml
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.1-devel as base
WORKDIR /app

RUN apt update && apt install python3-pip -y && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
RUN make
CMD ["python3","run.py"]
```

actually, I modified some code in run.py then published, the user should pull image more than 300MB.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you question correctly you want to take advantage of Docker layer to reduce the bytes that needs to get pulled when you release an update of your container.

In order to achieve this you should split your layer so that the static (and presumably big) file are in a separate layer with respect to the dynamic (presumably small) files.

You could achieve this by having a dedicated `static` folder and issue 2 separate `COPY`: one for the static directory and one for everything else (taking care of excluding the static directory itself!).

Given your current structure intermingle static and dynamic resources, it's a little bit more cumbersome as you cannot just `COPY` and entire folder and be done with it. In your case the command should be something like:

```
# Preparing layers for static resources
COPY static_files/*.param static_files/
COPY static_folders/folder* static_folders/

# Copying the rest of the resources
COPY static_files/*.py static_files/
COPY static_folders/*.py static_folders/
COPY dynamic* run.py requirements.txt .
```

This however is quite clumsy and error prone (you could easily forget to adjust the Dockerfile when you add a new static resource with a new name pattern) and will also result in a bunch of layer instead of just 2 distinct static vs dynamic layers. So it would be probably worth evaluating whether changing the project structure can be a worthwhile investment in the long run.

Comment: thanks, I'll change my project structure to fit this.